# Derivative of an integral with change of variable.

Tags: integration, derivatives, substitution

I have this problem.
I want to compute the following integral in terms of $z$, where $x = az$

$$
\frac{d}{da}\int a^2x^2dx
$$

Computing the integral first, the derivative as the last passage, I obtain what I believe to be the correct solution, i.e.,

$$
\frac{d}{da}\int a^2x^2dx = \frac{d}{da}\left(a^2 \frac{x^3}{3}\right) = \frac{d}{da}\left(a^2 \frac{a^3z^3}{3} + c\right) = 5a^4\frac{z^3}{3}
$$

and the same by substituting first in the integral, keeping in mind that $dx = a dz$,

$$
\frac{d}{da}\int a^2x^2dx = \frac{d}{da}\int a^2(az)^2 adz \frac{d}{da}\int a^5z^2 dz = \frac{d}{da}\left(a^5 \frac{z^3}{3}\right) = 5a^4\frac{z^3}{3}.
$$

Things start to get messy when I take the derivative inside the integral, i.e.,

$$
\frac{d}{da}\int a^2x^2dx = \int 2ax^2dx = \int 2a a^2z^2 adz = 2a^4\frac{z^3}{3}.
$$

One might argue that I need to keep in consideration also of $d/da x$, since $x$ depends on $a$, after all. However, I still obtain a wrong result

$$
\frac{d}{da}\int a^2x^2dx = \int a^2 \frac{d}{da}\left(x^2\right) + 2a x^2 dx = \int \left( a^2 \frac{d}{da}\left(a^2z^2\right) + 2a a^2z^2  \right)adz \\
= \int 2a^4z^2 + 2a^4z^2dz = 4a^4\frac{z^3}{3}.
$$

Since I am obtaining three different results, I must be making at least two different mistakes; I wonder where these mistakes are. (sorry for being lazy and not including the constant $c$ from the integrals)

Comment: At first you wrote $a^2x^3$ inside of the integral and then $a^2 x^2$ wich is the correct one?

Comment: Taking derivative inside the integral - first one is wrong for the reason you state. Even the second one is wrong, again because $x$ is function of $a$. You took care of it in $a^2x^2$ but what about $dx$?

Comment: Ah, do I understand correctly that I have also to take care of $d/da (dx)$?

Comment: @JonatanGarcia thanks for pointing that out. $a^2x^2$ is the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We substitute $x=az$ right from the beginning and obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{d}{da}\int a^2x^2dx}&=\frac{d}{da}\int a^2(az)^2d(az)\\
&=\frac{d}{da}\left(a^5\int z^2 dz\right)\tag{1}\\
&=\left(\int z^2 dz\right)\left(\frac{d}{da} a^5\right)\tag{2}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(\frac{1}{3}z^3+C\right)\left(5a^4\right)}\tag{3}\\
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use $d(az)=adz$ and factor out $a$.
- In (2) we factor out the constant part.
- In (3) we integrate and differentiate.

> Next we look at OPs final approach somewhat more detailed. Since OP wants to compute the integral with respect to $z$ we consider $x=x(z)=az$ as function of $z$. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{d}{da}\int a^2x^2\,dx&=\frac{d}{da}\int a^2x^2(z)\,d\left(x(z)\right)\\
> &=\frac{d}{da}\int a^2 x^2(z) x^{\prime}(z)\,dz\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

We are now ready to do the differentiation with respect to $a$ before the integration. To better see what's going on we write
$x=x(z,a)$ and $x_z(z,a)$ instead of $x^{\prime}(z)$ to indicate that we differentiate with respect to $z$.

> We obtain from (4) by successively applying the multiplication rule $(u\,v)^{\prime}=u^\prime v+uv^\prime$
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{d}{da}}&\color{blue}{\int a^2 x^2(z,a) x_z(z,a)dz}\\
> &=\int \frac{d}{da} \left(a^2 \cdot \left(x^2(z,a) x_z(z,a)\right)\right)dz\\
> &=\int 2a \left(x^2(z,a) x_z(z,a)\right)dz\\
> &\qquad +\int a^2\frac{d}{da}\left(x^2(z,a) x_z(z,a)\right)dz\\
> &=\int 2a \left(x^2(z,a) x_z(z,a)\right)dz\\
> &\qquad +\int a^2 \left(2x(z,a) \left(\frac{d}{da}x(z,a)\right) x_z(z,a) +x^2(z,a)\frac{d}{da} x_z(z,a)\right)dz\\
> &=\int 2a \left((az)^2 a\right)dz\\
> &\qquad +\int a^2 \left(2(az)\left(z\right) a + (az)^2\cdot 1\right)dz\\
> &=2a^4\int z^2\,dz+2a^4\int z^2\,dz + a^4 \int z^2dz\\
> &=5a^4\int z^2dz\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=5a^4\left(\frac{1}{3}z^3+C\right)}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with (3).

Comment: Thanks, but this does not address my question. I also arrived at the same solution. My problem begins when I bring the differentiation inside the integral. And sometimes I need to do that because I don't know (fully) the expression $d/da \int f(a, x) dx$

Comment: @Sam: I've added some info regarding your last approach.

Comment: I notice my error now. I did not differentiate x_z(z, a), thanks

Comment: @Sam: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is helpful. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Leibniz integral rule states that for a convergent integral:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^Xf(x,t)dx=\int_0^X\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}dt$$
so you can "bring the differential inside the integral". However in this case remember that $x=x(a)$ and so you have to bare that in mind. Also, I feel that when you subbed in $x=az$ you forgot that $dx=adz$

---

$$\begin{align}
I(a)=&\int a^2x^3 dx=\int a^2(az)^3 adz=a^6\int z^3dz\\
=&a^6\frac{z^4}{4}
\end{align}\\
\therefore I'(a)=\frac{6}{4}a^5z^4=\frac32a^5z^4$$

Comment: Are sure you wrote correctly the first equation? shouldn't the right-hand integral still be in $dx$?

Comment: you could, but what would be the integral $z\,dx$

Comment: I do not really understand your first equation. What I would have wrote  is $d/dt \int f(x, t) dx = \int d/dt f(x, t) dx$.

Comment: @Sam that is not true, the rule applies to definite integrals (you can rewrite yours as one) but when you have multiple variables you have to specify that it is a partial differential

Comment: I see, I actually had the doubt that I could not bring the differentiation inside the integral when is not defined. Still remains very foggy why you transform $dx$ in $dt$. And actually, you are not changing $X$. It is very confusing for me. I guess I should read about Leibniz integral rule

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, by the way.